# VBA Macro, get URL from given range loop

Tags: vba, excel

The way my code is currently set up, it gets the data from the URL that i've indicated in the code. However, I actually want to provide a list of URLs in Sheet2 that it would loop through until it's extracted all data. I dont want to have to update the code each time individually per URL. There are thousands... How would i be able to do that?

Here is the code:

```
 Public Sub exceljson()
    Dim https As Object, Json As Object, i As Integer

    Dim Item As Variant

    Set https = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    https.Open "GET", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=USD&tsyms=BTC", False
    https.Send

    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(https.responseText)

    i = 2
    For Each Item In Json.Items
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = Item
        i = i + 1
    Next
    MsgBox ("complete")
End Sub
```

Comment: Read the Sheet2 range of URLs in a string array and loop the array doing the rest of your code

Comment: Do you know what that would look like? Im a complete noob :(

Answer (score 2):

I'll just pretend that all of the URLS are in Column A here:

```
Public Sub exceljson()
    Dim https As Object, Json As Object, i As Integer, j As Integer

    Dim Item As Variant

    Set https = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    For j = 1 to Sheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.count
        If Len(Trim$(Sheets(2).Cells(j, 1).Value2)) > 0 Then
            https.Open "GET", Trim$(Sheets(2).Cells(j, 1).Value2), False
            https.Send

            Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(https.responseText)

            i = 2
            For Each Item In Json.Items
                Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = Item
                i = i + 1
            Next Item
        End If
    Next j

    MsgBox ("complete")
End Sub
```

I like to use the trim() method to be safe that I'm not catching anything extra

Comment: Hey, i just tried it and it errors out on this line: If Len(Trim$(Sheets(2).Range("A" & i).Value2)) > 0 Then

Comment: oof, yeah my bad that should be `If Len(Trim$(Sheets(2).Range("A" & j).Value2)) > 0 Then` the key part being that I had put i instead of j initially

Comment: with thousands of urls i would still consider using an array or collection to loop rather than continually revisiting the worksheet.

Comment: @QHarr that's a really good point, I don't usually work with such large sets of data

Comment: Thanks but its still giving me the same error? Is there something else there? Would you be able to try it from your end to see what you get?

Comment: I didn't follow my initial qualifier when I said "I'll pretend the URLS are in Column A:"  `Range("A"&j)` Instead it would be `Range(j&"A")` in both locations

Comment: Okay, this time I think I've got it. In a previous edit I had it as `Range("A"&j)` but that wasn't iterating the way that I initially had said it would. Then I had added 1 to count because I was thinking that it was a necessary step since I had shifted from starting index of 0, but the .count actually returns the last row.

Comment: That looks a lot better - most people will have the `UsedRange` starting from cell A1, so the possible error introduced by basing row count on `UsedRange` rather than the actual sheet probably won't matter.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me through that. I obviously should've made some mock data to debug that and probably would've ironed that out pretty quickly. >_>

Comment: Yeah, sometimes things look so simple that we don't bother to test, and it's always those times that we trip over the little things :D